# Forecasting weather data with Keras. How do I choose the dates to predict? How can I map the predicted data?

Tags: keras, lstm

Ich bin in der Sackgasse. Ich versuche Keras und komme einfach nicht weiter.

https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/

How do I choose the dates to predict? (If that is temperature, pressure or humidity, how can I add wind direction prediction in addition to this?)

How can I map the predicted data? (Is it temperature, pressure or humidity...?)

How can I predict more than just one point in the future? (One point is not enough, I would like to show the weather trend.)

```
def show_plot(plot_data, delta, title):
labels = ["History", "True Future", "Model Prediction"]
marker = [".-", "rx", "go"]
time_steps = list(range(-(plot_data[0].shape[0]), 0))
if delta:
    future = delta
else:
    future = 0

plt.title(title)
for i, val in enumerate(plot_data):
    if i:
        plt.plot(future, plot_data[i], marker[i], markersize=10, label=labels[i])
    else:
        plt.plot(time_steps, plot_data[i].flatten(), marker[i], label=labels[i])
plt.legend()
plt.xlim([time_steps[0], (future + 5) * 2])
plt.xlabel("Time-Step")
plt.show()
return
```

for x, y in dataset_val.take(5):
show_plot(
[x[0][:, 1].numpy(), y[0].numpy(), model.predict(x)[0]],
12,
"Single Step Prediction",
)

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAivb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ezXr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkyf7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baGRQ.png)

I can't assign the data correctly.